# Bedeutung von "menscheln"

Tags: verb, regional, meaning

Seit ungefähr 15 Jahren kenne ich das Wort **menscheln** und ich dachte immer, es hieße, dass in einer Umgebung (wie zum Beispiel einem Meeting oder einem Parteitag), wo sonst eher Objektivität und Kühle oder Konkurrenzdenken herrscht, plötzlich menschliche, fast familiäre Wärme auftaucht... Das ganze mit einem leicht ironischen Touch.

Nun lese ich im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/menscheln), dass es "*menschliche Schwächen deutlich werden lassen*" bedeuten soll. In Grimms Wörterbuch schließlich steht zusätzlich noch die Bedeutung "*nach Mensch riechen*".

Jetzt bin ich verwirrt, denn ich war von meiner Version sehr überzeugt. Befindet sich dieses Wort im Wandel? Ist die "*menschliche Wärme*"-Bedeutung regional (bin aus Berlin)?

Comment: Ich höre das Wort gerade übrigens zum ersten mal. Was auch immer es bedeutet, es ist am Niederrhein nicht sehr gebräuchlich.

Comment: Kann @Em1 da nur zustimmen. Habe dieses Wort noch nie gehoert.

Comment: Ich habs schon mal gelesen: http://www.schuellers-im-netz.de/Grafik/Cliparts/Fun/Menscheln.jpg

Comment: oh das überrascht mich ein bisschen. Ich hätte gedacht, dass das bekannt ist... nicht so sehr im Alltag aber in den Medien

http://www.faz.net/faz-net-fruehkritik-guenther-jauch-der-bricht-dir-noch-das-herz-11964991.html?selectedTab=images&showMarginalSlot=0&offset=0

es gibt noch viele andere Beispiele

Answer (score 9):

Ich und kenne den Begriff "menscheln" nur in der von dir beschriebenen Bedeutung. Ein Beispiel:

Eine bisher unauffällige Mitarbeiterin einer Firma verlässt seit zwei Wochen ihren Arbeitsplatz fast täglich 20 Minuten zu früh. Als sie zur Rede gestellt wird, gibt sie glaubhaft an, ihr Sohn läge im Krankenhaus. Wenn sie bis Dienstschluss bliebe könne sie ihren Sohn wegen der schlechten Zugsverbindung nicht mehr besuchen. Die Geschäftsführung zeigt Mitgefühl und erlaubt ihr bis zur Entlassung des Kindes auch weiterhin 20 Minuten früher zu gehen. Als sie das ihren Kollegen erzählt, sagen diese: "Wer hätte das gedacht? Es menschelt ja doch noch in unserem Betrieb."

Den Duden-Eintrag "menschliche Schwächen deutlich werden lassen" würde ich daher durch "menschliche *Tugenden* deutlich werden lassen" ersetzen wollen.

Da ich aus Österreich bin und den Begriff erstmals in Graz, dann in Leoben und später auch in Wien gehört habe, du aber angibt, ihn in dieser Bedeutung in Berlin gehört zu haben, halte ich ihn nicht für eine regionale Spezialität. Allerdings gibt es wenig Gelegenheiten wo der Gebrauch dieses Wortes in dieser Bedeutung angemessen ist, daher hört man dieses Wort sehr selten.

Ngram: http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=menschelt%2Cmenscheln&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: oh danke für das n-gram... ich habe auch geguckt aber ich habe nicht an "menschelt" gedacht :)

Answer (score 7):

Interessant - mir ging es genau umgekehrt: Ich kannte das Wort bisher *nur* in der leicht pejorativen Bedeutung. Hat mir auch immer eingeleuchtet (man beachte die parallele Konstruktion bei "fischeln" = nach Fisch riechen). Ähnlich wie bei "allzu menschlich" ist allerdings auch eine gewisse Sympathie impliziert.

Dass es "menschliche Wärme" und "Mitmenschlichkeit" bedeuten soll, ist mir völlig neu. Aber vielleicht gibt es ja tatsächlich regionale Unterschiede (for the record: bin Bayer :))

Früher scheint es jedenfalls so gewesen zu sein:

> MENSCHELN, *verb. sich menschlich zeigen:* weil nu der lebendig
>   unverkocht affect noch menschlend, der haut förcht, und nicht umb der
>   bissigen scharpfen warheit willen leiden wil. S. Frank *weltb. vorr. A
>   5a; **schwäb**.* menschlen, *nicht besser sein als die menschen gewöhnlich
>   sind:* es menschlet bei ihm halt auch. Schmid 382; ***schweiz***. menschelen,
>   *menschliche gebrechlichkeiten an sich haben und äuszern,* er
>   menschelet, *fehlt, ist nicht besser als andere,* es menschelet, *riecht
>   nach gebrechlichkeit.* Stalder 2, 208; ***auch im bairischen sprachgebiet***:
>   menscheln, *menschlich, fehlerhaft handeln,* es tuet auch bei den besten
>   leuten oft menschelen, *es ist menschenart* Schöpf 434. *sonst heiszt
>   unpersönliches* menscheln *nach menschen riechen, von einem schlecht
>   gelüfteten zimmer z. b. sagt man* hier menschelts (*vgl. auch* menschern
>   1). <sup>[Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemid=GM03737)</sup> [fette Hervorhebung v. mir]

Offenbar also ein ursprünglich primär eher südd. Ausdruck.

---

Edit: Vielleicht noch ein paar ungeformte Gedanken dazu - unter Umständen OT:
Je mehr mir diese Frage im Hinterkopf herumgeht, desto mehr sieht es für mich danach aus, dass hier mehrere diffuse Begriffsdefinitionen zusammentreffen. So beschreiben für mich "menschliche Wärme" und "Mitmenschlichkeit" ganz klar nur positive Aspekte in der sozialen Interaktion, im aktiven Handeln. Wenn jemand also "menschliche Wärme" zeigt oder "mitmenschlich" handelt, ist er nett bis karitativ. Möglicherweise kann man das Ganze auch anders sehen, eher vom Rezipienten her: jemand verspürt "menschliche Wärme" oder erlebt sich als "Mitmensch", wenn er sich nicht allein fühlt, wenn er erlebt, dass auch andere Leute "menschliche Schwächen" haben. Dann wird aus der canoo-Definition bzw. aus Emanuels Verständnis auch ein Schuh. - Wie gesagt, reine Spekulation. Gibt's Meinungen dazu?

Comment: Bei uns im Schwabenland *menschelet* es schon immer und überall, wobei auch bei uns die menschliche Schwäche ganz im Vorgdergrund steht.

Comment: das ist echt komisch... hier noch ein Beispiel aus einer Zeitung, das positiv ist:

http://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/article112282128/Chinas-Parteifuehrung-laesst-menscheln.html

vielleicht hat sich das Wort in Zeitungsdeutsch gewandelt

Comment: @Emanuel: Hmm, möglich! Ich habe noch ein paar andere Gedanken gehabt - siehe Edit.

Answer (score 3):

die Definition [unpersönlich: Mitmenschlichkeit, menschliche Züge zeigen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/menscheln)
trifft am ehesten mein bisheriges Verständnis für den Ausdruck und dürfte ja nach Situation als Schwäche oder Stärke gewertet werden.

Comment: Ja, das hatte ich auch gelesen und das ist auch, wie ich das Wort kenne. Deshalb haben mich die "offizielleren" Erklärungen ja so überrascht

Answer (score 2):

Bei der im Duden angegebenen Version muss es sich nicht zwangsläufig um einen Widerspruch zu Deiner Interpretation handeln. Befindet man sich in einer Situation, in der klares Denken erfordert wird, kann man es durchaus als Zeichen von Schwäche sehen, wenn Emotionen durchscheinen.

Comment: Da könntest Du noch einen Schritt weiter gehen und sagen, dass unser schwacher Geruchssinn dafür sorgt, dass wir menschliche Gerüche nicht feststellen, wenn wir die Distanz wahren. Rücken wir eng zusammen, riechen wir uns auch. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe es so aufgefasst, dass im Gegensatz zur Kontrollierbarkeit und Vorhersehbarkeit der Maschine beim Wort „es menschelt“ der unvorhersehbare und sowohl manchmal bedauerliche und ungünstige aber eben auch manchmal durch seinen spontanen, überraschend-unbürokratischen und entgegenkommenden Ausdruck, der „human error“ gemeint ist (eben ohne das Wort „error“ ausschließlich negativ im Sinne von Fehler zu interpretieren, sondern ihm auch die menschliche Entscheidungsfreiheit zuzugestehen, im Sinne von „ah, da machen wir mit Augenzwinkern eine Ausnahme oder wenden flexibel den Hausverstand an um glimpflich im Sinne aller Involvierten zu handeln!“) (bin aus Österreich)

Answer (score 0):

"Menscheln" wird insgesamt selten verwendet, obwohl das Phänomen, das es beschreibt, häufig ist. Es geht dabei um gekränkte Eitelkeit, Neid, das Gefühl, dass einem ein geringerer Status zugestanden wird als einem eigentlich zusteht. Auch ein bisschen um Illusionen und unerfreuliche Verhaltensweisen, die letztendlich das fragile Ego schützen sollen. Wurde mir gegenüber schon benutzt um Verhalten des Klerus oder von Ärzten an Universitätskliniken zu beschreiben.

"So brauchst du mit mir nicht umzugehen/Ich kann mit dir so umgehen", "Du brauchst nicht zu glauben dass du etwas besseres bist/Ich bin etwas besseres als du anhand meiner eigenen Kriterien", "Deine Leistungen wurden durch unfairen Vorteil erlangt/Meine Leistungen werden verkannt", solche Dinge.